# Dirac Delta and FFT in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

Theoretically, the use of Fourier Transform with the Dirac Delta Function allows for the production of exponential functions in the time domain if Dirac Delta functions are in the frequency domain. I have tried to carry out this idea for the following code in an attempt to use sound waves to encode information stored in the frequency domain.

I've been working on a project to send data via sound waves.
The way I've carried this out is by encoding the data in pulses in the frequency domain, and then creating a unique sound wave containing that information.  I've used python to plot that, which has given me:

```
import scipy as sp
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


paynowString = "00020101021126380009SG.PAYNOW010100211+658128992803010520400005303702545800.005802SG59006009Singapore620401006304"

characters = []

def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

characters = split(paynowString)
print(characters)

ascii_characters = [ord(char) for char in characters]
print(ascii_characters)

positive_x_domain = np.zeros(9*len(ascii_characters))

rhs = []
xr = list(positive_x_domain)
for i in range(len(ascii_characters)):
    rhs = rhs + xr[i*9:(i*9+9)]+[ascii_characters[i]]
positive_x_domain = rhs + xr[(i+9)*9:]
positive_x_domain = np.asarray(positive_x_domain)
print(positive_x_domain)

negative_x_domain = np.flip(positive_x_domain)
print(negative_x_domain)

origin = np.array([0])

x_domain = np.concatenate((negative_x_domain, origin), axis = None)
x_domain = np.concatenate((x_domain, positive_x_domain), axis = None)
print(x_domain)


plt.plot(np.arange((-(len(x_domain)-1)/2), ((len(x_domain)-1)/2)+1), x_domain)
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.xlabel('Time [samples]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

After which, this gives me a graph that represents the frequency domain:
[image: Frequency Domain]

Following this, I then apply the Fourier Transform on the frequency graph to get:

```
sound_wave = fft.ifft(x_domain)

plt.plot((-(len(x_domain)-1)/2), (((len(x_domain)-1)/2)+1), sound_wave)
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.xlabel('Time [samples]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.axis([-0.1, 2500, -0.1, 1])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
#end of sending the sound wave
```

This gives me another graph that represents the sound wave:

[image: Sound Wave]

In this attempt, I tried to carry this out by making sample points in the frequency domain to represent the Dirac Delta function, but this does not give me a periodic sound wave as the result due to the issue of not producing a completely exponential function in the time domain.
Is there any way I can change my representation in the frequency domain to properly emulate the Dirac Delta function such that the result in the time domain is periodic? Or is there a better alternative that allows me to produce a periodic sound wave in the time domain without using the Dirac Delta function?

Comment: Your original data isn't periodic in the sense that the string sequence isn't periodic. If you put `paynowString = "000000002222222200000000222222220000000022222220000000022222222000000002222222200000000"` you will notice the resulting plot is periodic & mirrored about its centre.

Comment: Do note that the origin, as far as the FFT is concerned, is the first sample, not the one in the middle (for both the frequency and the time domain). Apply `ifftshift` to move the origin from the middle to the first sample, and `fftshift` to move it back to the middle: `sound_wave = fft.fftshift(fft.ifft(fft.ifftshift(x_domain)))`

Comment: @Chris Luengo Thank you very much for the comment, it really helped. Could you please explain what ifftshift and fftshift do to help make the sound wave come out periodic?